# Setting up SCSS compilation in a custom theme in Grav CMS

Tags: sass, grav

Trying to get to grips with Grav and have created a completely new theme from scratch using (or in my early stages of understanding, basically copying) the bare minimum from the default Quark theme.

I have got the base files and folders in place but I am struggling to figure out what I am meant to do, to get the SCSS compilation working.

I am working on a CentOS 7 Linux server with Plesk installed.

I know there is probably different ways of theming in Grav but whilst I am learning the system, I want my custom theme to work like the Quark one. I have set up the `scss` folder in the theme folder along with the `css-compiled` folder for the compiled CSS to be moved into.

I have included a screenshot of the theme structure below (should this be of any use):

[image: Grav theme folder structure]

I am not sure if I need to be installing something on the server (Node.js/npm and Gulp.js for example) or if this should be happening automatically.

If I need to be setting something up on the server, then this will raise additional questions I think but I just need someone to point me in the right direction as I had no idea who/where to ask this...

If I point the @import commands in my theme.scss file to import directly from the Quark theme as explained in the ['Customisation' documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/customization), still no CSS is generated for the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile the SCSS on localhost, you need to do the following:

- [Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and install Node (including its package manager 'npm')
- `$ cd user/themes/mytheme`
- Load the (dev)dependencies listed in package.json: `$ npm install`
  This will load everything needed: Gulp, the SCSS compiler etc.
- Compile the SCSS files by running the 'build' script from package.json: `$ npm run build`
  This will run the 'build()' function inside `gulpfile.js`
- In folder `/user/themes/mytheme/css-compiled`, you should now find files with a new date.

Now you can follow the docs from Grav on [Customising SCSS](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/customization#custom-scss-less) to make your own changes to SCSS. If you run `$ npm run dev`, Gulp will automatically compile your SCSS when it detects changes.

Note: I have assumed `package.json` and `gulpfile.js` are copied from Quark.